# How to prove that its a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I prooved that QN=NO using the converse of the mid point theorem. How can i prove that PNLO is a parallelogram? I first joined PN and OL to form a quadrilateral. In that only one side is parallel one diagonal is bisected. So how to prove that its a parallelogram?

Comment: The answer is obvious is you make AB short and AD long.

Answer (score 3):

Move B towards A. The length of BC tends to 0 and that of CD to AD. (And by Thales, BC is shorter than CD.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the angle bisector is perpendicular to the opposite side - that is, when the angle bisector is also the altitude -  you have two congruent triangles and the angle bisector is also the median.

You can make this argument work for any two of these three [cevians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cevian).

Comment: Ok. That means if the angle bisector acts perpendicular to the opposite side then it bisects the opposite side equally. Right ?

Comment: Yes - look up the meaning of "altitude". You should be able to finish the formal proof.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I think you meant to say "congruent", not "similar"

Comment: @Vasya Fixed thanks. You could have.

Answer (score 0):

The angle bisector is also the median if and only if the triangle is an isosceles triangle in which case the bisector is also the altitude.

In general these are three different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using algebra:

Without loss of generality, we can move the triangle so that the point we're drawing our lines through is at $A = (0,0)$, and the other two points are at $B = (1,0)$ and $C = (h,k)$.

The midpoint of the far line $BC$ then is at $\left(\frac{h+1}{2},\frac{k}{2}\right)$, and thus the midpoint line is $y = \frac{k}{h+1}x$.

Meanwhile, using the half angle formula $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$, we get the angle bisector of $A$ as $y=\frac{k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2} + h}x$.

These obviously aren't the same line in general, but we can characterize the situations where they are by setting the slopes to being equal.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{k}{h+1}&=\frac{k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2} + h}\\
\sqrt{h^2+k^2}+h&=h+1\\
\sqrt{h^2+k^2}&=1\\
h^2+k^2 &= 1\\
\end{align}$$

... which is exactly the unit circle around the origin.  So $B$ and $C$ are both exactly $1$ unit away from $A$, which means that $A$ **is the apex of an isosceles triangle**!